# How to subtract multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

I have the above cells and i want to substract each individual row . i.e. 137.61-137.61, 132.88-270.49 and print each one of the results on the respective row cell next to them . I know i can do `=(A1-B1)` to each individual row but is there a shorter way to do that for all the cells ?

Comment: If your data extend down, say 50 rows, then you could select C1:C50, enter your formula in C1, and then press CTRL + Enter to have it propagate down the column

Comment: or if you have Office 365 with the dynamic formula you can do: `=A1:A50-B1:B50` and will spill down automatically.

Comment: Use a table and just insert the formula once if you are really working with excel 2010. The rest will auto-populate

Comment: Yes @JvdV Sir, using Table Structure will be the fastest, just missed the basics of excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After subtracting for the first operation, when you hold the cursor from the right and drag it to the last cell, it will automatically subtract all of them.

If you want watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ElcsZpA3h4&ab_channel=ExcelTutorialsbyEasyClickAcademy